# Cleaning Up Dissolved Faces And Random Vertexes

Tags: vertices, faces

The image shows off how I make my models for interiors and exteriors of buildings, which is to say I measure everything out and I'm left with a messy model with way too many faces. But when I go about dissolving faces, such as the selected windows here, and then I separately go and dissolve the faces around the cleaned up ones, I'm left with a bunch of vertex points.

How should I get rid of them? I don't want to select all and then dissolve because then the separate faces will all join up, I only want to get rid of the random vertex points along otherwise smooth faces.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me [Limited Dissolve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/delete.html#limited-dissolve) can help in this situation. It can dissolve all vertices between vertices of which the angle of the connecting edges and faces are below a certain given angle value.

[image]